El identificador del Set de pruebas no se encuentra registrado para realizar proceso de habilitación
Registre el Facturador con software propio en la Dian y configure el set de pruebas y estoy usando SoapUI para enviar las facturas, pero me da el siguiente error diciendo que el Set de pruebas no se encuentra registrado para realizar proceso de habilitación
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"

xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">

<s:Header>

    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">

        http://wcf.dian.colombia/IWcfDianCustomerServices/GetStatusZipResponse</a:Action>

    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"

        xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">

        <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">

            <u:Created>2024-07-29T18:19:48.387Z</u:Created>

            <u:Expires>2024-07-29T18:24:48.387Z</u:Expires>

        </u:Timestamp>

    </o:Security>

</s:Header>

<s:Body>

    <GetStatusZipResponse xmlns="http://wcf.dian.colombia">

        <GetStatusZipResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DianResponse"

            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

            <b:DianResponse>

                <b:ErrorMessage i:nil="true"

                    xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />

                <b:IsValid>false</b:IsValid>

                <b:StatusCode>2</b:StatusCode>

                <b:StatusDescription>Set de prueba con identificador

                    447e7b88-18db-4e95-a8a3-45123830d753 no se encuentra registrado para

                    realizar proceso de habilitación.</b:StatusDescription>

                <b:StatusMessage i:nil="true" />

                <b:XmlBase64Bytes i:nil="true" />

                <b:XmlBytes i:nil="true" />

                <b:XmlDocumentKey i:nil="true" />

                <b:XmlFileName i:nil="true" />

            </b:DianResponse>

        </GetStatusZipResult>

    </GetStatusZipResponse>

</s:Body>

</s:Envelope>
qué proceso debo realizar para corregir este error, he intentado volver a registrar el software propio, pero me sigue retornando ese error.
agradecería su ayuda.
